# Imageview visibility in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

In the following code how to hide the image at the start of the APP.So when the user enters the password then show it back again

```
package com.app.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyappActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView.setVisibilty(View.INVISIBLE);
    Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String prepwd="password";
            EditText  et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwd);
            if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(prepwd))
            {
                ImageView iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im1);
            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can modify the visibility of a view with `view.setVisibility(x);`, where x is `View.INVISIBLE`, `View.VISIBLE`, or `View.GONE`.

You should probably define the image as invisible in your layout XML... `android:visibility="invisible"`

You can't set visibility on ImageView as your code shows, you must `findViewById()` to get the view to set visibility on. You seem to be doing that with your `iv` variable already, so just call the `setVisibility()` method on it.