# the first row of the customerAdapter does not work

Tags: android, custom-adapter

I have a list view that if a value is 0 attaches an image, if it is 1 not.
the value 0 and 1 derives from an SQLdatabase

I cannot understand why the first row is ALWAYS showing the image also if it is marked as 1, the xml text has just an ImageView and textView so i do not send you

```
  public class CustomViewAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

 public final int VIEW_TYPE_STARS=0;
 public final int VIEWTYPE_NORMAL=1;

public static class ViewHolder{
  public final  ImageView iv;
  public final  TextView tv;

    public ViewHolder(View view){
        iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.urgent_finger);
        tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_v1);


    }
}



public CustomViewAdapter(Context context,Cursor c, int flag){
    super( context, c, flag);



}
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)   {

  int viewType = getItemViewType(cursor.getPosition());

    int layoutId=-1;
      layoutId = R.layout.textview_pretty_cool2_layout;




   View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
 ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
 view.setTag(viewHolder);
   return view;



}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
ViewHolder viewHolder= (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    String isCheckedMaybe = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(UcanContract.Tasks.COLUMN_URGENCY));
    Integer toString = Integer.parseInt(isCheckedMaybe);

     if(toString==0){
       viewHolder.iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.edit_undo);
        String tasksText = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(UcanContract.Tasks.COLUMN_TASKS));
        viewHolder.tv.setText(tasksText);

    }else if (toString == 1){
        String tasksText = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(UcanContract.Tasks.COLUMN_TASKS));
        viewHolder.tv.setText(tasksText);
    }

}
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Visisbility` of your `ImageView` & `TextView` to GONE and when you need it you set it to `VISISBLE` and it will work for you

Comment: It works thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445726/imageview-visibility-in-android

Comment: okay sir, im glad it did, you are satisfied the checkmark it accepted. that's the norm here, you can also upvote@trocchietto

Comment: I need 15 reputation( at the moment I am 1) to upvote you, and I can't upvote my self. I saved this in the bookmarks as soon as my reputation will be 14 points more I will indeed come back to you upvoting, cool stuff I spent day on this issue, is counterintuitive because the way i did it, avoiding to put the image icon in xml and calling it in bindview overidde as in the class above was logical. You saved me, my project is almost ready for my assignment.

Comment: okay Sir, and good luck on your assignments, but you can accept it even if you do not have reps, and also do you still need answers on all your questions you have asked on stackoverflow? @trocchietto

Comment: OK thanks, today i received +5 rep, I will come back to you Mr. Elltz

Comment: no SIr you do not get it, what i mean is you can accept an answer if it solves your problem. i have understood you on the upvote, & i can help you with that, all i am saying is just accept it Sir, Mr.@trocchietto check this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)